# Using .loc with on subset of levels from a DataFrame with MultIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Given a dataframe with 3 levels of multiindex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat({'a': pd.Series([1,2,3,1]),
                'b': pd.Series([5,4,3,5]),
                'c': pd.Series(range(9,13)),
                'd': pd.Series(range(13,17))}, axis=1).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>>         d
    a b c       
    1 5 9   13
    2 6 10  14
    3 7 11  15
    4 8 12  16
```

I want to use loc with a list of indices from the first 2 levels:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1, 2], [5, 4]], names=('a', 'b'))
>>> MultiIndex([(1, 5),
                (2, 6)],
               names=['a', 'b'])
```

I tried to use .loc with individual indices:

```
df.loc[idx[0]]
>>>      d
    c     
    9   13
    12  16

df.loc[idx[1]]
>>>      d
    c     
    10  14
```

I expected `df.loc[idx]` to return the same result as

```
pd.concat([df.loc[i] for i in idx])
>>>     d
    c     
    9   13
    12  16
    10  14
```

But I `df.loc[idx]` returns

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (3,) (2,2)
```

Is there something cleaner than `pd.concat([df.loc[i] for i in idx])` to obtain the expected result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a MultiIndex expects the same levels, a workaround might be to set the extra levels as columns temporarily:

```
levels = df.index.names.difference(idx.names)

out = df.reset_index(levels).loc[idx].set_index(levels, append=True)
```

Or [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=idx), how='right')
```

Output:

```
         d
a b c     
1 5 9   13
    12  16
2 4 10  14
```

If you want to drop `a`/`b` in the process:

```
levels = df.index.names.difference(idx.names)
out = df.reset_index(levels).loc[idx].set_index(levels)
```

Or:

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=idx), how='right').droplevel(idx.names)
```

Output:

```
     d
c     
9   13
12  16
10  14
```

Comment: I tried the first trick and found it ugly, but I like the join option, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Treat the index as a list of tuples and pass to [janitor.select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

# index sorting is done here 
# to avoid performance warning
df.sort_index().select(rows=list(idx))

         d
a b c     
1 5 9   13
    12  16
2 4 10  14
```

Another option is with a dictionary:

```py
# a safer option would be to use get_level_values
# instead of levels
rows=dict(zip(idx.names, idx.levels))
df.select(rows=rows)

         d
a b c     
1 5 9   13
    12  16
2 4 10  14
```

Another option with `pd.xs`:

```py
df = df.sort_index()
selected = [df.xs(key=tup, drop_level=False) for tup in idx]
pd.concat(selected)

         d
a b c     
1 5 9   13
    12  16
2 4 10  14
```